# Variables in CSS, is that possible?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to make CSS dynamic? I want to set a variable in the CSS file. Something like this:

```
var baseColour = #000; 
body{
  background-colour: baseColour;
}
```

I want to let the user choose a colour. Then I want to set the variable in CSS to the user input with JavaScript.

Is that possible? Or at least that one with the variable?

Comment: Use a CSS preprocesor, for example [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: Look at [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: You can make CSS dynamic with javascript, php, asp...

Comment: as a choice of user, you might have to use cookies to keep the setup through page visited

Answer (score 2):

No CSS can't do this by default, you may want to use SASS for something like this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10918954)

Comment: I think it's the most simple and direct answer to his main question.